# Angular2 testing service mocks

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I have a simple Angular2 component that consists of the following

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {FooterLinksService} from './footer-links.service';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-footer-links',
        templateUrl: './footer-links.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./footer-links.component.css'],
        providers: [FooterLinksService]
    })
    export class FooterLinksComponent implements OnInit {        

        constructor(private footerLinksService: FooterLinksService) {
            let footerLinks = this.footerLinksService.LoadFooterLinks();
        }    

    }
```

I am trying to write the unit tests with Jasmine for this.  Now I want to mock the FooterLinksService, but most of the examples I have seen involve manually writing a FooterLinksServiceMock.  Is there any other approach I can use which autogenerates the mock service like NSubStitute and I provide the expected returns values from footerLinksService.LoadFooterLinks

Comment: Read the jasmine documentation. Mocks and spies are covered.

Comment: I actually saw this, but the problem is that all the examples I came across, even on the Angular site https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html seem to point to actually creating a mockedService (FooterLinksService) instead of using speis?  Is this the standard approach and if so why not go through spies

Comment: Probably because the documentation tries not to introduce too many concepts at the same time, and also to show code that is not specific to jasmine. If you understand what a mock and a spy are, you can of course use jasmine to create them rather than doing it manually. Why couldn't you? And what's preventing you from trying anyway?

Comment: Also note that the official angular documentation for tests does make use of jasmine spies. Just search for spy in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @JBNizet, you could just use a spy. What you would do is get the actual service inside the test, then you can spy on a method an return any arbitrary value, when that method is called. It might look something like

```
describe('component: FooterLinksComponent', () => {
  let fixture;
  let service;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        FooterLinksComponent
      ],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooterLinksComponent);
    service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(FooterLinksService);
  });

  it('should change message returned', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'LoadFooterLinks').and.returnValue('Hello new message');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.message).toBe('Hello new message');
  });
});
```

You will need to move the code where you access the service from inside the constructor into the `ngOnInit`. The reason for this is because

1. You are using `@Component.providers`, so the service will not be created until the component is created.
2. When the component is created, the constructor is already called. So this doesn't give time for you to set up the spy. When you use `ngOnInit`, the `ngOnInit` is not called until you call `fixture.detectChanges()`

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. Does your `FooterLinkService` injects `Http` (from `@angular/http`) in its constructor? If so, is there any chance that your project is a public project (so I can take a look at your code to help me solve my issue)? Thanks!

Comment: @DavidL You still need to `imports: [ HttpModule ]`