# jasmine test cases dependency in angular 2 with stub

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-routing, stubs

Here I'm new to angular 2 test cases with jasmine + karma and I'm following this [testing guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html)  I tried to write test case but unable to write correctly and getting routing error as test cases are going to server while running, although it should not.
There is a question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358858/angular-2-with-jasmine-test-component-with-injected-service) but didn't help me to solve the problem. Please guide me.

Here is my component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Checklist } from './checklist';
import { Job } from '../+job/job'; 
import { OriginalService } from './original.service';
import { UserService } from '../core/user/user.service';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-selector',
    templateUrl: './original.component.html',
    providers: [OriginalService]
})
export class OriginalComponent implements OnInit {
  items = []
  job: Job;
  checklist: Checklist;
  user: any;
  shopId: any;
  jobId: any;

  constructor ( private orgService: OriginalService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, userService: UserService) {
     this.user = userService.user();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .map(params => params['job_id'])
      .subscribe(
         job_id => this.jobId = job_id
      );
      this.getChecklist();
      this.getJob();
  }

  getChecklist() {
    this.orgService.getChecklists({
      jobId: this.jobId
    })
    .then(checklist=> {
       this.gotJobdata = true;
       this.checklist = checklist.response})
    .catch(error => this.error = error);
  }

  getJob(){
    this.orgService.getJob({
     jobId: this.jobId
    })
    .then(job => this.job = job.response)
    .catch(error => this.error = error);
  }
}
```

Here's my service

```
import { Injectable, ViewChildren }    from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Checklist } from './checklist'; 
import { Job } from '../+job/job';
import { UserService } from '../core/user/user.service';

@Injectable()

export class OriginalService {
 shopId: any;

 constructor(private http: Http, private userService: UserService ) {
   this.shopId = userService.shopId();
 }

  getChecklists(svc): Promise<Checklist> {
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + this.shopId + '/jobs/' + svc.jobId + '/checklists_path/' + 'check_item.json')
     .toPromise()
     .then(response => response.json())
     .catch(this.handleError);
  } 

  getJob(svc): Promise<Job> {
    return this.http.get(return environment.apiUrl + this.shopId + '/jobs/' + svc.jobId + '.json')
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

Here's the spec what I've tried:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap'; 
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { ComponentLoaderFactory } from 'ng2-bootstrap/component-loader';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { UserService } from '../core/user/user.service';
import { OriginalService } from './original.service';
import { OriginalComponent } from './original.component';

describe('OriginalComponent', () => {

  let component: OriginalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OriginalComponent>;
  let params: Subject<Params>;
  let userService, orgService;

  let userServiceStub = {
   isLoggedIn: true,
   user: { name: 'Test User'}
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
   params = new Subject<Params>();
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({

   imports: [ ModalModule.forRoot(), SharedModule, HttpModule ],  
   declarations: [ OriginalComponent ],
   providers: [ OriginalService, UserService, ComponentLoaderFactory,
    { provide: Router, useValue: userServiceStub }, {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { params: params }} ]
   })
   .compileComponents();
 })
);


beforeEach(() => {

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChecklistComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();

  it('should create', () => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

> Please correct me how to properly use routing in test cases or stubs where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: when I run the test cases, It goes to API call from service with undefined Id, and returning routing error from server.